# Trying to make dynamic option form

Tags: php, forms, dynamic

OK I try this for days and I can't do it so I try to take it step by step first I need to get the info from the database correctly and show it in a form here is the database

```
CategoryID  |  CategoryName  |    ParentID

----------------------------------------
1           | FirstMenuCat1  |      0
2           | FirstMenuCat2  |      0
3           | SubMenuCat1    |      1
4           | SubMenuCat2    |      1
5           | SubMenuCat3    |      2
```

and here is my last attemp that worked so I know I get the correct data from database but I don't know how to make it a form:

```
<?php
require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');
$q = "SELECT CategoryName FROM menus where ParentID = '0' ORDER by CategoryID";
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc));

/* associative array */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
printf ("%s\n", $row["CategoryName"]);



}
 ?>
```

Here is my attempt to make it but its not working

```
/* associative array */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

foreach($row){
                echo "<option value=\"". urlencode( $_ ) ."\" $selected >$_</option>\n";
                $selected = ""; // only the first element will be marked as selected
}

}
 ?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at **option** tag i think you are trying to create a combobox list. If it is then  First of all do not use \n. The options in a combobox list already shown line by line.

Secondly you have not printed the **select** tag. Without it the list will not be rendered properly. Try the following code:

```
echo "<select name='mylist'>";

$selected = "selected";
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) !== FALSE){
   echo "<option value='". $row['key']."' $selected >".$row['value']."</option>";
   $selected = ""; // only the first element will be marked as selected
}

echo "</select>";
```

hopefully it may help.

Comment: it worked!!  can you explain me what this line is needed? $selected = "'selected'"; and why you use $i++;

Comment: echo "<select name='mylist'>"; and why i need this?

Comment: oops, i think i have mistakenly put $i++. Let me remove it. $selected is used because we want to select the first line. In echo "selected" will be written to tell the browser that this item is the default one. However, the code may also work if you remove the $selected, because in most browsers the first element is selected by default.

Comment: @AntMar you need this because till will render the select tag without this you options will not work

Comment: "<select name='mylist'>" This is the select tag to create an options list in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
echo '<select name="" id="">';
/* associative array */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

// Check the $_ correctly
foreach($row){
        echo "<option value='". urlencode( $_ ) ."'>$_</option>\n";
}

}

echo '</select>';
```

Note*: First element by default will be selected for the dd.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think this is what you need

```
$optionString = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{

   $value         = urlencode($row['CategoryName']);
   $optionString .= "<option value='{$value}'>{$row['CategoryName']}</option>";


 }

 echo "<select>$optionString</select>";
```

Comment: Your first value will be selected by default .. no need to make it selected explicitly

Answer (score 0):

```
$selected = 'selected';

$htmlSelect = '<select name="elementName" id="elementId">';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $htmlSelect .= '<option value="' . urlencode( $_ ) . '" ' . $selected . ' >' . $_ . '</option>';
    $selected = ""; // only the first element will be marked as selected
}

$htmlSelect .= '</select>';

echo $htmlSelect;
```

**Note 1:** It's better to use double quote `"` instead of single quote `'` on element attributes. Some browsers don't like single quotes.

**Note 2:** Couldn't understand why you're using `foreach` again in the `while` statement.

**Note 3:** If you will not remember which option was selected there is not any need to specify which element is selected, first one will be selected by default.